# R lapply using stringi and rbind

Tags: r, lapply, rbind, stringi

I'd like to split out some data within a data frame by a specific string and count the frequency.

After toying with a few methods I've come up with a method, but there's a slight error in my results.

Example:

Data frame data file:

```
data
abc hello
hello
aaa
zxy
xyz
```

List:

```
list
abc
bcd
efg
aaa
```

My code:

```
lapply(list$list, function(x){
    t <- data.frame(words = stri_extract(df$data, coll=x))
    t<- setDT(t)[, .( Count = .N), by = words]
    t<-t[complete.cases(t$words)]
    result<-rbind(result,t)
    write.csv(result, "new.csv", row.names = F)
})
```

In this example I would expect a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file with the following results:

```
words Count
abc     1
aaa     1
```

However with my code I got:

```
words Count
aaa     1
```

I know `stri_extract` should identify `abc` within `abc hello` so perhaps the error happens when I use `rbind`?

Comment: See also: `stringi::stri_list2matrix`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `write.csv` file out of the loop, otherwise it will override the previously saved file and you will only get the file saved at the final stage. By doing that, you will have to `rbind` your result outside `lapply`, since you can't modify the `result` variable in the function.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list$list, function(x){
                                t <- data.frame(words = stri_extract(df$data, coll=x))
                                t<- setDT(t)[, .( Count = .N), by = words]
                                t<-t[complete.cases(t$words)]
                                t
 }))

write.csv(result, "new.csv", row.names = F)
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Comment: Couldn't you have write.csv within the loop with append=T? That would probably just slow down the process anyway, I only need to write once, just asking

Comment: That is a viable solution, too. You can go ahead and have a try. Not sure about the performance.